# How can I export an SQLite table as insert statements?

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently I'm just running

```
SQLiteDatabase db = DB_Helper.getWritableCustom();
db.rawQuery("select 'insert into tasks_ordered values' || group_concat(a,',') || ';' as b from (\n" +
            "select '(' ||\n" +
            "\n" +
            "CASE typeof(_id) WHEN 'text' THEN \"'\" || REPLACE(_id,\"'\",\"''\")  || \"'\" WHEN 'null' THEN 'null' WHEN 'blob' THEN 'blob??' ELSE _id END\n" +
            " ||','|| CASE typeof(_task_id) WHEN 'text' THEN \"'\" || REPLACE(_task_id,\"'\",\"''\")  || \"'\" WHEN 'null' THEN 'null' WHEN 'blob' THEN 'blob??' ELSE _task_id END\n" +
            " ||','|| CASE typeof(type) WHEN 'text' THEN \"'\" || REPLACE(type,\"'\",\"''\")  || \"'\" WHEN 'null' THEN 'null' WHEN 'blob' THEN 'blob??' ELSE type END\n" +
            " \n" +
            "|| ')' as a from tasks_ordered \n" +
            ")",null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
String inserts = cursor.getString(0);
cursor.close();
```

Here's the query without java escaped characters:

```
select 'insert into tasks_ordered values' || group_concat(a,',') || ';' as b from (
select '(' ||

CASE typeof(_id) WHEN 'text' THEN "'" || REPLACE(_id,"'","''")  || "'" WHEN 'null' THEN 'null' WHEN 'blob' THEN 'blob??' ELSE _id END
||','|| CASE typeof(_task_id) WHEN 'text' THEN "'" || REPLACE(_task_id,"'","''")  || "'" WHEN 'null' THEN 'null' WHEN 'blob' THEN 'blob??' ELSE _task_id END
||','|| CASE typeof(type) WHEN 'text' THEN "'" || REPLACE(type,"'","''")      || "'" WHEN 'null' THEN 'null' WHEN 'blob' THEN 'blob??' ELSE type END

|| ')' as a from tasks_ordered 
);
```

Example output of query:

```
insert into tasks_ordered values(0,null,10),(1,null,11),(2,591,0),(3,603,0),(4,627,0),(5,null,12),(6,639,0),(8,675,1),(9,699,1),(10,711,1);
```

But it just feels like overkill. is there a sys method I can use directly instead of reinventing the wheel every time?

Comment: A content provider may be better. I know it sounds more complicated at first but if you search for "content provider generator" then you can create tables from a json configuration file

Comment: I mostly want the tables as inserts because I want to debug the database in another application, this way i just batch run and can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd copy the entire database file but that does assume using an SQLite compatible application.

However, another approach would be to have your own generic method. The following being an example (not fully tested, so may need work for floats, blobs and escaping strings) :-

```
public static String getTableInsertStatements(SQLiteDatabase db, String table) {
    if (table.length() < 1) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
    //String values = "";
    Cursor csr = getAllRowsFromTable(db,table,true,null);
    long rowcount = csr.getCount();
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            if (i==0) {
                values.append(" (");
            }
            switch (csr.getType(i)) {
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                    values.append("null");
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                    values.append(Long.toString(csr.getLong(i)));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                    values.append(Double.toString(csr.getDouble(i)));
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                    String unescaped_string = csr.getString(i);
                    // NEED TO HANDLE ESCAPING HERE
                    //values.append("'" + unescaped_string + "'");
                    // Limited ESCAPING 
                    values.append("'" + unescaped_string.replace("'","''") + "'");
                    break;
                case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                    values.append("X'" +  getBytedata(csr.getBlob(i),2147483647) + "'");
                    break;
            }
            // Add comma separator between values in current column unless last column
            if (i < (csr.getColumnCount() - 1)) {
                values.append(",");
            }
            // Add closing parenthesis after the last value of the row
            if (i == csr.getColumnCount() - 1) {
                values.append(")");

            }
        }
        if (!csr.isLast()) {
            values.append(",");
        }
    }
    if (values.length() > 1 ) {
        return "INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES " + values.toString() + ";";
    }
    return "";
}
```

The above utilises other common utilities so the entitre Class (CommonSQLiteutilities) is :-

```
public class CommonSQLiteUtilities {

    public static final boolean ERROR_CHECKING_ON = true;
    public static final boolean ERROR_CHECKING_OFF = false;

    // SQLite MASTER TABLE definitions
    static final String SQLITE_MASTER = "sqlite_master";
    static final String SM_TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN = "type";
    static final String SM_NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    static final String SM_TABLENAME_COLUMN = "tbl_name";
    static final String SM_ROOTPAGE_COLUMN = "rootpage";
    static final String SM_SQL_COLUMN = "sql";
    static final String SM_TYPE_TABLE = "table";
    static final String SM_TYPE_INDEX = "index";

    static final String PRAGMA_STATEMENT = "PRAGMA ";
    static final String PRAGMA_DATABASELIST = "database_list";
    static final String PRAGMA_USERVERSION = "user_version";
    static final String PRAGMA_ENCODING = "encoding";
    static final String PRAGMA_FOREIGNKEYLIST = "foreign_key_list";
    static final String PRAGMA_INDEXINFO = "index_info";
    static final String PRAGMA_INDEXLIST = "index_list";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO = "table_info";

    static final String PRAGMA_DBLIST_SEQ_COL = "seq";
    static final String PRAGMA_DBLIST_NAME_COL = "name";
    static final String PRAGMA_DBLIST_FILE_COL = "file";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_CID_COL = "cid";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_NAME_COl = "name";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_TYPE_COL = "type";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_NOTNULL_COL = "notnull";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_DEFAULTVALUE_COL = "dflt_value";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_PRIMARYKEY_COL = "pk";
    static final String CSU_TAG = "SQLITE_CSU";

    private CommonSQLiteUtilities() {}

    /**
     * Write Database information to the log;
     * Information wrttien is:
     * the database path, (will/should show connected databases)
     * the version number (note! user version i.e. version coded in DBHelper),
     * the tables in the database (includes android_metadata but not sqlite_master),
     * the columns of the tables
     * @param db    The SQLite database to be interrogated
     */
    public static void logDatabaseInfo(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // Issue PRAGMA database_list commnand
        Cursor dblcsr = db.rawQuery(PRAGMA_STATEMENT + PRAGMA_DATABASELIST,null);
        // Write databases to the log
        while (dblcsr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"DatabaseList Row " + Integer.toString(dblcsr.getPosition() + 1) +
                    " Name=" + dblcsr.getString(dblcsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_DBLIST_NAME_COL)) +
                    " File=" + dblcsr.getString(dblcsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_DBLIST_FILE_COL))
            );
        }
        dblcsr.close();
        // Issue PRAGMA user_version to get the version and write to the log
        //Note! to set user_version use execSQL not rawQuery
        Cursor uvcsr = db.rawQuery(PRAGMA_STATEMENT + PRAGMA_USERVERSION,null);
        while (uvcsr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Database Version = " +
                    Integer.toString(uvcsr.getInt(uvcsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_USERVERSION))));
        }
        uvcsr.close();
        // Select all table entry rows from sqlite_master
        Cursor tlcsr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                        SQLITE_MASTER + " WHERE " +
                        SM_TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN + "='" + SM_TYPE_TABLE + "'"
                ,null);
        // For each table write table information to the log
        // (inner loop gets column info per table)
        while (tlcsr.moveToNext()) {
            String current_table = tlcsr.getString(tlcsr.getColumnIndex(SM_TABLENAME_COLUMN));
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,
                    "Table Name = " + current_table +
                            " Created Using = " + tlcsr.getString(tlcsr.getColumnIndex(SM_SQL_COLUMN)),
                    null
            );
            // Issue PRAGMA tabel_info for the current table
            Cursor ticsr = db.rawQuery(PRAGMA_STATEMENT + PRAGMA_TABLEINFO +
                            "(" + current_table + ")",
                    null
            );
            // Write column info (see headings below) to the log
            while (ticsr.moveToNext()) {
                Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Table = " +
                                current_table +
                                " ColumnName = " +
                                ticsr.getString(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_NAME_COl)) +
                                " ColumnType = " +
                                ticsr.getString(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_TYPE_COL)) +
                                " Default Value = " +
                                ticsr.getString(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_DEFAULTVALUE_COL)) +
                                " PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = " + Integer.toString(
                        ticsr.getInt(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_PRIMARYKEY_COL))
                        )
                );
            }
            ticsr.close();
        }
        tlcsr.close();
    }

    /**
     * Generic get all rows from an SQlite table,
     * allowing the existence of the table to be checked and also
     * allowing the ROWID to be added AS a supplied string
     *
     * @param db                    The SQLiteDatabase
     * @param tablename             The name of the table from which the
     *                              returned cursor will be created from;
     *                              Note!
     * @param use_error_checking    Whether ot not to try to detect errors
     *                              currently just table doesn't exist,
     *                              true to turn on, false to turn off
     *                              ERROR_CHECKING_ON = true
     *                              ERROR_CHECKING_OFF = false
     * @param forceRowidAs          If length of string passed is 1 or greater
     *                              then a column, as an alias of ROWID, will be
     *                              added to the cursor
     * @return                      the extracted cursor, or in the case of the
     *                              underlying table not existing an empty cursor
     *                              with no columns
     */
    public static Cursor getAllRowsFromTable(SQLiteDatabase db,
                                             String tablename,
                                             boolean use_error_checking,
                                             String forceRowidAs) {
        String[] columns = null;

        // Tablename must be at least 1 character in length
        if (tablename.length() < 1) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +
                    " is finishing as the provided tablename is less than 1 character in length"
            );
            return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});
        }

        // If use_error_checking is true then check that the table exists
        // in the sqlite_master table
        if (use_error_checking) {
            Cursor chkcsr = db.query(SQLITE_MASTER,null,
                    SM_TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN + "=? AND "
                            + SM_TABLENAME_COLUMN + "=?",
                    new String[]{SM_TYPE_TABLE,tablename},
                    null,null,null
            );

            // Ooops table is not in the Database so return an empty
            // column-less cursor
            if (chkcsr.getCount() < 1) {
                Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Table " + tablename +
                        " was not located in the SQLite Database Master Table."
                );
                // return empty cursor with no columns
                return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});

            }
            chkcsr.close();
        }

        // If forcing an alias of ROWID then user ROWID AS ???, *
        if(forceRowidAs != null && forceRowidAs.length() > 0) {
            columns = new String[]{"rowid AS " +forceRowidAs,"*"};
        }

        // Finally return the Cursor but trap any exceptions
        try {
            return db.query(tablename, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Exception encountered but trapped when querying table " + tablename +
                    " Message was: \n" + e.getMessage());
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Stacktrace was:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create and return a Cursor devoid of any rows and columns
     * Not used, prehaps of very little use.
     * @param db    The Sqlite database in which the cursor is to be created
     * @return      The empty Cursor
     */
    private static Cursor getEmptyColumnLessCursor(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});
    }

    /**
     * Write column names in the passed Cursor to the log
     * @param csr   The Cursor to be inspected.
     */
    public static void logCursorColumns(Cursor csr) {
        Log.d(CSU_TAG,
                new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +
                        " invoked. Cursor has the following " +
                        Integer.toString(csr.getColumnCount())+
                        " columns.");
        int position = 0;
        for (String column: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            position++;
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Column Name " +
                    Integer.toString(position) +
                    " is "
                    + column
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write the contents of the Cursor to the log
     * @param csr   The Cursor that is to be displayed in the log
     */
    public static void logCursorData(Cursor csr) {
        int columncount = csr.getColumnCount();
        int rowcount = csr.getCount();
        int csrpos = csr.getPosition(); //<<< added 20171016
        Log.d(CSU_TAG,
                new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +
                        " Cursor has " +
                        Integer.toString(rowcount) +
                        " rows with " +
                        Integer.toString(columncount) + " columns."
        );
        csr.moveToPosition(-1);     //Ensure that all rows are retrieved <<< added 20171016
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String unobtainable = "unobtainable!";
            String logstr = "Information for row " + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition() + 1) + " offset=" + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition());
            for (int i=0; i < columncount;i++) {
                logstr = logstr + "\n\tFor Column " + csr.getColumnName(i);
                switch (csr.getType(i)) {
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is NULL";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                        logstr = logstr + "Type is FLOAT";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is INTEGER";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is STRING";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is BLOB";
                        break;
                }
                String strval_log = " value as String is ";
                String lngval_log = " value as long is ";
                String dblval_log = " value as double is ";
                String blbval_log = "";
                try {
                    strval_log = strval_log + csr.getString(i);
                    lngval_log = lngval_log + csr.getLong(i);
                    dblval_log = dblval_log +  csr.getDouble(i);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    strval_log = strval_log + unobtainable;
                    lngval_log = lngval_log + unobtainable;
                    dblval_log = dblval_log + unobtainable;
                    try {
                        blbval_log = " value as blob is " +
                                getBytedata(csr.getBlob(i),24);
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                logstr = logstr + strval_log + lngval_log + dblval_log + blbval_log;
            }
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,logstr);
        }
        csr.moveToPosition(csrpos); // restore cursor position <<< added 20171016
    }

    public static String getTableInsertStatements(SQLiteDatabase db, String table) {
        if (table.length() < 1) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder values = new StringBuilder();
        //String values = "";
        Cursor csr = getAllRowsFromTable(db,table,true,null);
        long rowcount = csr.getCount();
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            for (int i=0; i < csr.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                if (i==0) {
                    values.append(" (");
                }
                switch (csr.getType(i)) {
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                        values.append("null");
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                        values.append(Long.toString(csr.getLong(i)));
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                        values.append(Double.toString(csr.getDouble(i)));
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                        String unescaped_string = csr.getString(i);
                        // NEED To ESCAPE HERE
                        values.append("'" + unescaped_string + "'");
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                        values.append("X'" +  getBytedata(csr.getBlob(i),2147483647) + "'");
                        break;
                }
                // Add comma separator between values in current column unless last column
                if (i < (csr.getColumnCount() - 1)) {
                    values.append(",");
                }
                // Add closing parenthesis after the last value of the row
                if (i == csr.getColumnCount() - 1) {
                    values.append(")");

                }
            }
            if (!csr.isLast()) {
                values.append(",");
            }
        }
        if (values.length() > 1 ) {
            return "INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES " + values.toString() + ";";
        }
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Return a hex string of the given byte array
     * @param bytes     The byte array to be converted to a hexadecimal string
     * @param limit     the maximum number of bytes;
     *                  note returned string will be up to twice as long
     * @return          The byte array represented as a hexadecimal string
     */
    private static String getBytedata(byte[] bytes, int limit) {
        if (bytes.length < limit) {
            return convertBytesToHex(bytes);
        } else {
            byte[] subset = new byte[limit];
            System.arraycopy(bytes,0,subset,0,limit);
            return convertBytesToHex(subset);
        }
    }

    // HEX characters as a char array for use by convertBytesToHex
    private final static char[] hexarray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    /**
     * Return a hexadecimal string representation of the passed byte array
     * @param bytes     The byte array to be represented.
     * @return          The string representing the byte array as hexadecimal
     */
    private static String convertBytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexstr = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            int h = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
            hexstr[i * 2] = hexarray[h >>> 4];
            hexstr[i * 2 + 1] = hexarray[h & 0xF];
        }
        return new String(hexstr);
    }
}
```

As a test I used the following :-

```
    imgdbhlpr = new ImgDBHelper(this);
    CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(imgdbhlpr.getWritableDatabase());
    Cursor csr = CommonSQLiteUtilities.getAllRowsFromTable(imgdbhlpr.getWritableDatabase(),ImgDBHelper.TBLNAME,true,null);
    CommonSQLiteUtilities.logCursorColumns(csr);
    CommonSQLiteUtilities.logCursorData(csr); 
    Log.d("INSERTSTMNT",CommonSQLiteUtilities.getTableInsertStatements(imgdbhlpr.getWritableDatabase(),ImgDBHelper.TBLNAME))
```

The generated insert statement being :-

> INSERT INTO images VALUES  (1,'Image 001','image001.JPG'), (2,'Image
>   002','image002.JPG'), (3,'Image 003','image003.JPG'), (4,'Image
>   004','image004.JPG'), (5,'Image 005','image005.JPG'), (6,'Image
>   006','image006.JPG'), (7,'Image 007','image007.JPG'), (8,'Image
>   008','image008.JPG'), (9,'Image 009','image009.JPG'), (10,'Image
>   010','image010.JPG');

The entire Output being :-

```
12-14 17:59:00.253 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/user/0/mjt.sqliteexamples/databases/myimagestore
12-14 17:59:00.254 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Database Version = 1
12-14 17:59:00.257 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
12-14 17:59:00.257 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
12-14 17:59:00.269 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = images Created Using = CREATE TABLE images(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT,path TEXT)
12-14 17:59:00.270 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = images ColumnName = _id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
12-14 17:59:00.270 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = images ColumnName = description ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
12-14 17:59:00.270 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = images ColumnName = path ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
12-14 17:59:00.274 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: logCursorColumns invoked. Cursor has the following 3 columns.
12-14 17:59:00.274 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Column Name 1 is _id
12-14 17:59:00.274 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Column Name 2 is description
12-14 17:59:00.274 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Column Name 3 is path
12-14 17:59:00.274 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: logCursorData Cursor has 10 rows with 3 columns.
12-14 17:59:00.274 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Information for row 1 offset=0
                                                For Column _id Type is INTEGER value as String is 1 value as long is 1 value as double is 1.0
                                                For Column description Type is STRING value as String is Image 001 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
                                                For Column path Type is STRING value as String is image001.JPG value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
......
12-14 17:59:00.277 2963-2963/? D/INSERTSTMNT: INSERT INTO images VALUES  (1,'Image 001','image001.JPG'), (2,'Image 002','image002.JPG'), (3,'Image 003','image003.JPG'), (4,'Image 004','image004.JPG'), (5,'Image 005','image005.JPG'), (6,'Image 006','image006.JPG'), (7,'Image 007','image007.JPG'), (8,'Image 008','image008.JPG'), (9,'Image 009','image009.JPG'), (10,'Image 010','image010.JPG');
```

#### Finally using the generated INSERT :-

In SQLite Manager (tool I use) I then used `CREATE TABLE images(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT,path TEXT)`  to create the table.

- (as grabbed from the output as per line `12-14 17:59:00.269 2963-2963/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = images Created Using = CREATE TABLE images(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT,path TEXT)`)

Again in SQLitae manager I copied and pasted the generated INSERT statment and excecuted it, the resultant table then  being :-

[image]

***Note! as previously stated, this hasn't been fully checked, but would likely just need minor modifications (e.g. escaping has not been done, nor have I checked double/floats or blobs).***

#### Further testing

Testing against a database with pseudo randomly generated values. Floats appear to work and BLOBS appear to work.

e.g.

The Source table looks like (using something that I have for viewing database information within an App) :-

[image]

Whilst the table created using the generated insert statement looks like (in SQLite Manager) :-

[image]

*BLOBS if short enough to be displayed are displayed as hex if too long then as `BLOB size(??)`*

The generated INSERT statements for the above being :-

```
INSERT INTO testtable2 VALUES 
(1,'The quick fox was brown but couldn''t jump the fence, but tried so wasn''t that lazy.','The quick fox was brown but couldn''t jump the fence, but tried so wasn''t that lazy.',121.0), (2,1234.5678,X'4228290870402E6421527E45301777586D0945242F0F32766E4100046F6B6A053378633E2377126E3A1A71031D2B21522C3A74793B532D1E142B3E502D6A2D5778595D2316781D0D03183B136121396A222E1E1D20086E54',121.0), (3,X'5F1B681C033D7E7C60641146362F3E48276035220C200D','0.0.0.0',678946.0),
 (4,'This is not a BLOB','0.0.0.0','The quick fox was brown but couldn''t jump the fence, but tried so wasn''t that lazy.'), 
(5,1,'This is not a BLOB',1.0), ......
```

Comment: It is better than my method because it can decode blobs apparently.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in method.
The `sqlite3` shell implements the same output (`.mode insert`) with equivalent code.